# Why does RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN in BigDecimal division round 0.45 to 0.5?

Tags: java, rounding, numeric, bigdecimal

The rounding mode `HALF_EVEN` is supposed to round a (decimal) number ending in 5 to the closest *even* less precise number (e.g., 4.5 is rounded to 4, whereas 5.5 is rounded to 6).

Now, it seems that Java's division of `BigDecimal` is not obeying that rule; the following code gets it to round 0.45 to 0.5:

```
import java.math.*;

class Round {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal five = BigDecimal.valueOf(5);
        BigDecimal eleven = BigDecimal.valueOf(11);
        BigDecimal x = five.divide(eleven, 1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Output `0.5`
Note that 5/11 = 0.4545454545... so when looking at the first two digits after the decimal point, 0.45, we clearly would want to see that rounded to the nearest even neighbor, i.e. to 0.40, not 0.50.

Can anyone explain this?

(In case it matters, I'm running `java -version` = openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19)

#### Note:

1. This is not about rounding *before* getting a value into the BigDecimal; indeed
   the result is unchanged when using the string constructor

```
     BigDecimal five = new BigDecimal("5");
     BigDecimal eleven = new BigDecimal("11");
     BigDecimal x = five.divide(eleven, 1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

2. It also doesn't depend on the scale at which we round (as long as scale is odd), and you can scale the number up (e.g., round 500/11).

Comment: It's not rounding `0.45`, it's rounding `0.4545...`. That's closer to `0.5` than `0.4` no matter what the rounding mode is. You can truncate that to get `0.4`, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN):

> round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.

So it is needed to first decide whether both neighbours are equidistant.

> so when looking at the first two digits after the decimal point...

That's not sufficient to determine whether the value is equidistant is equidistant to both neighbours, which in this case is 0.4 and 0.5. We need to look at one more digit in this case.

In the case of 5/11, 5/11 is closer to 0.5 (distance = 0.045454545...) than to 0.4 (distance = 0.0545454...), so "round towards the even neighbor" is not applied, and "round towards the 'nearest neighbor'" *is*.

Comment: I get the difference and this sounds reasonable ... my assumption that one only looks at the next digit may have been simplistic.
BUT if that is the semantics of HALF_EVEN, it would (for some computations) be extremely expensive to decide, as we might need arbitrary precision to find out whether we are at the “exactly equidistant” case or the “just rather close” case.  Is that really true?  Can you share insight into how this is done/implemented?

Comment: In this case, one additional digit suffices; if the next digit is a 0, you need to keep going ...

Comment: @Sebastian Okay I brainfarted :) I tried looking around the implementation, but couldn't find an answer to that (perhaps ask a new question?). Though intuitively, the number of 0s like that appearing should be bounded by the scale & precision of the divisor and dividend, as well as the desired scale.